# Does the Rogue's Reliable Talent feature work for thieves' tools, since the rogue is proficient in them?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, skills, rogue, proficiency

Does the Rogue's Reliable Talent work for thieves' tools, since the rogue is proficient in them?

On PHB, pg. 96, it says when Reliable Talent is applicable:

> Whenever you make an ability check that lets you add your proficiency bonus

And on PHB, pg. 154, it says about using thieves' tools:

> Proficiency with these tools lets you add your proficiency bonus to any ability checks you make to disarm traps or open locks.

Based on this phrasing from the PHB, I believe it would indeed work for tools and kits, but I am looking for affirmation of my understanding.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Your interpretation is correct

You already quote all the necessary rules.

- Using Thieves' Tools usually involves an ability check
- Proficiency in Thieves' Tools lets you add your proficiency bonus to the check
- Reliable Talent works on any ability check where you add proficiency

Therefore, Reliable Talent will work on a check that uses Thieves' Tools if you are proficient with them